# Runtime error when deleting the middle node of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime-error

I am working on LeetCode problem [2095. Delete the Middle Node of a Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-the-middle-node-of-a-linked-list):

> You are given the `head` of a linked list. **Delete** the **middle node**, and *return the head of the modified linked list*.
>
> The **middle node** of a linked list of size `n` is the `⌊n / 2⌋`<sup>th</sup> node from the **start** using **0-based indexing**, where `⌊x⌋` denotes the largest integer less than or equal to `x`.
>
> - For `n` = 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, the middle nodes are 0, 1, 1, 2, and 2, respectively.

This is my code

```cpp
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* deleteMiddle(ListNode* head) {
        
        ListNode *slow = head ;
        ListNode *fast = head ;
        
        
        if(head==NULL){
            return head ;
        } 
        if(head->next == NULL){
            delete head ;
            return head ;
        }
        
        while(fast->next && fast){
            slow = slow->next ;
            fast = fast->next->next ;
        } 
        
        ListNode *temp = head ;
        
        while(temp->next != slow){
            temp=temp->next ;
        } 
        
        
        temp->next = slow->next ;
        delete slow ;
        
        return head ;
        
        
    }
};
```

I am getting runtime error as follows:

```
Line 27: Char 21: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:36:21
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

- After `delete head` you should not do `return head` as then you return a reference to freed memory, and the testing platform will certainly access that in order to test the result, leading to undefined behavior (or this error you got). Instead, you should `return nullptr`
- The `while` condition should *first* check that `fast` is not `nullptr` *before* checking what `fast->next` is, so these conditions should appear in reversed order.

With those fixes it will work.

Still, it is a pity that your code needs yet another pointer (`temp`) to walk through the list in order to find the node that precedes `slow`. It would be better to make sure `slow` is pointing to that preceding node to begin with... then you don't need that extra traversal through the list. You can achieve this by giving `fast` two steps advantage before starting the (first) loop.

Here is the code with the two problems fixed, and with the improvement I mentioned above:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* deleteMiddle(ListNode* head) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        
        if (head->next == nullptr) {
            delete head;
            return nullptr; // Don't return a reference to freed memory!
        }

        ListNode *slow = head;
        // Already advance `fast` with 2 steps, 
        //   so `slow` ends up BEFORE the node to delete
        ListNode *fast = head->next->next; 
        
        // First check that the fast pointer is not nullptr before accessing `->next`
        while (fast && fast->next) { 
            slow = slow->next;
            fast = fast->next->next;
        } 
        
        // No need for `temp` when we make sure `slow` is at the preceding spot
        // Reuse `fast` for referencing the node to delete
        fast = slow->next;
        slow->next = fast->next;
        delete fast;
        
        return head;
    }
};
```